# Cypress - Get page size (weight)?

Tags: cypress

Does anyone know if it is possible in Cypress to get not only the page load time but also its size? (megabytes)
I need get page speed and page size and save this in log file. I use this article https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/04/21/writing-performance-tests-cypress/ and page speed works, but i'm cant find how get page size (megabytes) of test page.

Answer (score 3):

Even i was trying the same ,Cypress didn't  give you pagesize but in javascript you can try below, I tried below Thing seems like working.

```
let s = document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0].outerHTML.length;
cy.log(s)
```

but not sure if it completely loads data of api returned as well. Still trying out few things ;)